# How can we construct a query containing Union with JoinSqlBuilder in SeviceStack OrmLite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a query like this where I need to union two tables and then join it with a third one

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM Table1 where col2_id = 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT * FROM Table2 where col2_id = 1) AS UnionList
INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t3.id = UnionList.col3_id
```

I am trying to use `JoinSqlBuilder` in ServiceStack OrmLite to build this query. I am able to create the join part but I am confused about how to create the Union part. Did not find any option/function which union's two table.